# Swift- updating global variable outside closure with completion handler

Tags: swift, closures, completionhandler

I've searched but I just can't figure out why my global array variable isn't getting updated in the global scope when I call this function. I've commented places in the code where I can print() the results I want but can't make it available outside the functions. I know it's something simple I'm not understanding about closures and completion handlers but I need someone else to have a look. Thanks.

```
import Foundation
import PlaygroundSupport

func pdate(month: String, day: String, year: String) -> String {
    let pdate = month + "/" + day + "/" + year
    return pdate
}

struct Phenomenon {
    var phenom: String
    var date: String
    var time: String
}

struct Apsides: Codable {
    let data: [Apsdata]?
    struct Apsdata: Codable {
        let phenom: String
        let year: String
        let month: String
        let day: String
        let time: String
    }
}

var arrFromURL: [(Phenomenon)] = []  //define a global I can use later- I know, globals are evil

func doURLsessions(completionHandler: @escaping (Phenomenon?)->()) {
    let sessionApsides = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)
    if let timeurl = URL(string: "http://api.usno.navy.mil/seasons?year=2018&tz=-8&dst=true") {
        (sessionApsides.dataTask(with: timeurl, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error: \(error)")
            } else if let data = data {
                let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
                let response = try? jsonDecoder.decode(Apsides.self, from: data)
                if (response?.data != nil) {
                    for item in [response?.data] {
                        for p in item! {
                            switch p.phenom {
                            case "Perihelion":
                                let perihelion = Phenomenon.init(
                                    phenom: p.phenom, date: pdate(month: p.month, day: p.day, year: p.year), time: p.time)
                                completionHandler(perihelion)
                            case "Aphelion":
                                let aphelion = Phenomenon.init(
                                    phenom: p.phenom, date: pdate(month: p.month, day: p.day, year: p.year), time: p.time)
                                completionHandler(aphelion)
                            default: ()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //print(arrFromURL) //This works fine, but not what I want
        })).resume()
    }
}

func chPhenom(phenom: String, date: String, time: String) {
    let p = Phenomenon.init(phenom: phenom, date: date, time: time)
    arrFromURL.append(p)
    //print(arrFromURL) //Also works fine,  but I want it's contents avilable outside this function
}

doURLsessions(completionHandler: {Phenomenon in
    chPhenom(phenom: Phenomenon!.phenom, date: Phenomenon!.date, time: Phenomenon!.time)
})

print(arrFromURL) //This just prints []- why isn't the global var available here? Is it printed before the asynch func finishes?

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

Comment: That URL doesn't seem to work. Not even from the browser. Gives a time-out error.

Comment: I just tried it, "http://api.usno.navy.mil/seasons?year=2018&tz=-8&dst=true". Seems to work for me?

Comment: @ChrisTaylor You understand correctly, `print(arrFromURL)` is called before the `completionHandler` is called. So you just print empty array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code in function `doURLsessions` is asynchronous - it isn't blocking other code from executing and since it is a network request it takes some time to finish. In your case `print(arrFromURL)` is called before `doURLsessions` is finished so `arrFromURL` is still empty.

Comment: Thanks. How do I make what doURLsessions produces available outside it's scope or the scope of the completion handler?

Comment: You either have to wait and access the result after doURLsessions is finished or continuously monitor `arrFromURL` and do something when it's value changes.

Comment: But your `arrFromURL` is available inside of `doURLsessions` completion handler, I would just continue your work from there:
 ```doURLsessions(completionHandler: {Phenomenon in
    chPhenom(phenom: Phenomenon!.phenom, date: Phenomenon!.date, time: Phenomenon!.time)
refresh()
})

func refresh() {
    print(arrFromURL)
}```

Comment: Good points- I need access to the contents of the array to update a label in my view controller that I have a IBAction connection established, and I can't seem to do that from inside my completion handler closure. As you suggest, I will try to monitor the array for updates.